# Google Sheets - Split Rows From Within One Cell and Drag adjacent Names to Match

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

I want the title in Cell A1 (Example Title) to be in a row next to each entry in Cell B1 so my desired result is:

[image]

In Excel OR Google Sheets. I only see "Split Text To Columns"

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to go about this. I'll suggest one of them.

Suppose that your raw data is in Sheet1!:A2:B. Add a "Sheet2" and make sure that A:B is empty. Then place the following formula in Sheet2!A1:

`=ArrayFormula(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(CHAR(10)&Sheet1!B2:B,CHAR(10),"~"&Sheet1!A2:A&"|"),"~",1,1)),"|"),"Select * WHERE Col2 Is Not Null"))`

To understand how this works, you need to work from the inside out.

First, an extra line break (`CHAR(10)`) is added to the start of each cell in B2:B. This is to create a uniform breaking point before every entry in the Column-B cells.

That now-uniform `CHAR(10)` is replaced by `REGEXREPLACE` with a concatenation of a tilde (`~`), the Sheet1!A2:A data for that row and a pipe symbol (`|`). Thus far, all of the virtually-held data for Sheet1!B2:B will still be within its original cell space.

`SPLIT` now splits that new data at the tilde to create individual horizontal cells that each now contain a separate copy of the Sheet1!A2:A label, a tilde, and *one* of the list items from Sheet1!B2:B.

This new virtual horizontal and vertical grid is then `FLATTEN`ed into one column.

Again, `SPLIT` is applied to separate the Sheet1!A2:A label from each of the now-individual Sheet1!B2:B entries, resulting in two columns.

'QUERY` is applied to keep only those results which are not null in the second column (ruling out any results for blank rows in the raw data or errors in column one formed by the previous functions, particularly those caused with the assumption that your number of individual data points in each cell of Sheet1!B2:B will vary).